# MongoDB/Mongochef: import from JSON changed dates to string

Tags: mongodb, import

I have a huge JSON file (about 5 GB) with several fields in all rows.
this is what one document looks like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f0105346c5110dfc6b8760"), 
    "patient" : "198", 
    "concept" : "Ampicillin", 
    "confidence" : NumberInt(100), 
    "value" : 1.0, 
    "time" : ISODate("2007-06-27T17:24:00.000+0000"), 
    "stay" : "20220"
}
```

This is data from hospital stays. 
For some reason, when I imported the JSON file to MongoDB (using mongoimport in linux command line), the 'time' field was saved not as ISO-date, but as a string. 
I figured - "no problem" and using mongo-chef altered the field to be of "Date" type using the 'Edit Value' option. I then picked the override option for all documents matching criteria.

[image: screencap of mongochef]

What happened then is that the entire collection got the exact same value in the "time" column.

So my question is - either - (A) how can I import it correctly, where mongoimport inserts the "time" as ISOdate, OR, (B) how can I correctly change it in mongochef, after the import.
This is time sensitive so PLEASE if anyone has any idea - help!

Thanks!

Comment: It is a bit odd that mongoimport did't handle this correctly.

what you can do is update strings to dataTime using forEach loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right. After digging a LOT I found the correct formatting is:

```
time: {$date:"2013-11-20T23:32:18Z"}
```

So I used 'sed' to change it throughout the json file and imported it.

I'm leaving this answer for the benefit of anyone who might come across this problem.

Comment: For MongoChef you have to add the millisecond part: `2016-03-07T20:03:46.157Z`

Comment: Is mandatory use `"$date"`, so `""` are mandatory. It is imported later how a `ISODate("same pattern used")` type